# Cypress get elements within specific path

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

Automating some tests with Cypress, I've found this issue.

We are asking many questions to the customers and these question will appear one-by-one depending on the previous answers. The next question (and for instance the kind of answer) will be unknown until it is shown. I leave this here as an example in which every 'div' (not 'rootDiv') is a question and they are only shown when the previous one has been responded.

```
    <div class="rootDiv">
        <div class="type1">
           <div class="type1b">
              <button class="button1">
              <button class="button1">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="type2">
           <div class="type2b">
              <button class="button2">
              <button class="button2">
              <button class="button2">
              <button class="button2">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="type1">
           <div class="type1b">
              <button class="button1">
              <button class="button1">
           </div>
        </div>
        .
        .
        .
       <div class="typeX">
           <div class="typeXb">
              <button class="buttonX">
              <button class="buttonX">
              <button class="buttonX">
              <button class="buttonX">
           </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

So the issues I am facing are:

1. Is there a way to access to the last 'div' within 'rootDiv', check its class and based on it click any of the buttons?
2. Is there a way to get the 'text' written on the buttons of the last 'div'?
3. Is there a way to have a list of elements (buttons in this case) and iterate through them?

There are many options to solve it, the main problem relies on how to get to those elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Is there a way to access to the last 'div' within 'rootDiv', check its class and based on it click any of the buttons?

It is possible to access the last 'div' within 'rootDiv': `cy.get('.rootDiv div').last()`. However, checking the class and then performing actions based on the value of the class is a bad idea, as it is [conditional testing](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/conditional-testing.html#Definition) and Cypress was not really made for it. Nevertheless, if you really need this attitude (no other, better ways), I think it is doable.

> 2. Is there a way to get the 'text' written on the buttons of the last 'div'?

Yes, it is possible to get 'text' of last div. `cy.get('.rootDiv div').last().invoke('text').then((textOnTheButton) => {console.log(textOnTheButton})`

> 3.Is there a way to have a list of elements (buttons in this case) and iterate through them?

To get all of the buttons all you need is `cy.get(button)`. If you want to iterate through all of them using index, you may use for loop and [eq()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/eq.html), however it may not be the best/most efficient solution for all cases.